# Isomorphism between Abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Let G, H be abelian groups. Prove that if $\phi$ : G $\rightarrow$ H is an isomorphism, then|g| = |$\phi$(g)|for all g in G, that is, the order of g is the same as the order of the image of g under $\phi$ .

Comment: Please avoid just asking stackexchange to do your homework for you. Try to explain any ideas you may have on solving this problem, or what about it you find confusing or difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Like Kyle said in the comment, if you have a question, you need to tell us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

I'll give you a hint.

if $\phi(x)$ is an isomorphims, then $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$. Also $\phi(e_{G}) = e_{H}$